# Каноникализация (канонизация) XML на C#

Tags: c#, xml, canonicalization

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите какими средствами можно канонизировать XML по [http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#](http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n) ?
Если не сложно, с примером...

Comment: @VladD Тогда я не понимаю проблему. Приводите к другому каноническому виду и подписывайте, почему обязательно к xml-exc-c14n? (Кстати, вы не путаете кэш и хэш?)  
Проблема в том что проверяет XML уже сторонний сервис, а ему как раз нужно xml-exc-c14n, иначе бы я не создавал тут три вопроса с надеждой что хоть на один будет ответ который даст возможность хотя бы вручную сформировать XML нужного вида.

Comment: @t1nk: Но ведь у вас уже есть класс, который умеет формировать нужный XML. (SignedXML?)

Comment: Он подписывает XML, не изменяя её. Все необходимые манипуляции выполняются в нём и до них мне не добраться потому что просто не у него ни свойств, ни методов посмотреть на канонизированную XML. Что он выдает, так это три тега которые нужно вставить в заголовок исходной XML, и все.

Comment: [XmlDsigC14NTransform Class][1] похоже на то что нужно, но, кажется, не совсем...


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform.aspx

Comment: А вы не думаете, что тот самый сторонний сервис отвергает ваш файл не потому, что он не в правильном xml-exc-c14n, а просто у него баг? Попробуйте послать гарантировано правильный xml-exc-c14n и проверьте результат.

Comment: Сервис принимает исходный подписанный XML. Канонизация нужна только для формирования подписи. Класс SignedXML канонизацию и все расчеты делает внутри выдавая только подпись, которая потом вставляется в заголовок исходной XML. Мне же нежно повторить подпись средствами JS. Уже есть криптографический плагин для браузера, проблема в том что да же кэш выдаваемый SignedXML и плагином не совпадает, а нужен для проверки подписи... Подозреваю канонизацию XML, потому мне нужно взглянуть на тот XML что получается внутри SignedXML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужным оказался [XmlDsigC14NTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigc14ntransform.aspx), нужно только добавить Body используемые в нем пространство имен родительских тэгов.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такая программа:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"in.xml");
        doc.Save(@"out.xml");
    }
}
```

превращает файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><directorylist><dir>/dev/null</dir><dir>/dev/zero</dir></directorylist>
```

в такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<directorylist>
  <dir>/dev/null</dir>
  <dir>/dev/zero</dir>
</directorylist>
```

Не уверен насчёт стандарта, но может быть, вам это подойдёт.

Comment: А не наоборот?  

Кстати по [xml-exc-c14n][1]

    [1]: http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n

Comment: Насчёт наоборот не знаю, я не изучал конкретный формат. А откуда вдруг взялся кэш в вопросе?

Comment: Ок, можно и без кэша, он собственно второстепенен сейчас...  
В любом случае это не та сериализация что мне нужна...  
Мне нужно что бы было соответствие рекомендациям xml-exc-c14n, а не просто форматирование.

Comment: А зачем вам именно этот формат, если не секрет? Не покатит просто одно каноническое представление?

Comment: @VladD, в [соседней ветке](http://hashcode.ru/questions/210116/canonicalization-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-xml) объясняется :)

Comment: @klopp: прочитал ветку, возможно невнимательно. Не понял, почему нельзя приведённый к xml-exc-c14n xml не считать каноническим, и приводить к (другому) каноническому виду.

Comment: Потому что нужно сделать "точно так, как делает класс SignedXML из C#". А как делает он - неизвестно :)

Comment: @klopp: то есть, нужно не "каноническое представление", а "представление по xml-exc-c14n"? Был введён в заблуждение заголовком вопроса. Почему тогда не воспользоваться этим самым "классом SignedXML"?

Comment: Если вы смотрели по ссылку, то в ней так и написано *Exclusive XML Canonicalization*.  
И именно этот каноническое представление мне нужно...

Comment: @t1nk: Всё же, а объясните, для чего вам. Надеюсь, не для сравнения XML как строк?

Comment: В *[соседней ветке][1]* я написал, что мне нужно канонизировать XML SOAP-а, для того что бы подписать её. Это нужно что бы потом можно было бы проверить подпись. Кроме того так сказано в рекомендациях (что нужно XML канонизировать перед подписыванием - нужно что бы рассчитать кэш и сформировать подпись).


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/210116/canonicalization-каноникализация-канонизация-xml

Comment: @t1nk: Тогда я не понимаю проблему. Приводите к _другому_ каноническому виду и подписывайте, почему обязательно к xml-exc-c14n? (Кстати, вы не путаете _кэш_ и _хэш_?)